# Quadratic relationship binary variable and a factor

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, lm

I have a set of data collected during over a year. We have created a variable called “bimonthly” (1=January-February; 2=March-April; 3=May-June; 4=July-August; 5=September-October and 6=November-December).

We also have a binary variable YES/NO (e.g. 0=no accident; 1=accident).

Data was collected for around 1000 participants but not as repeated measures (i.e. the binary variable was collected during just one period of two years so we have data for some participants in January-February but no more measures of these participants).

We have checked visually our distribution and we have found something like this: January-February= 40%; March-April= 50% May-June=60%; July August=60%; September-October=45% and November-December=40%). So, there is an increase and then a decrease (a quadratic relationship).

However, I would like to check it using a statistical test. I have tried with GLM and converting “bimonthly” as a factor. That gives information for bimonthly.L; bimonthly.Q; bimonthly.C; bimonthly^4 and bimonthly^5 but I am not sure this is correct. The results makes sense since the term bimonthly.Q is significant but not the other ones but I am not sure about the best method to analyse these data.

I have simulated the data, I hope this makes things much clear:

```
require(psych)

x1<-as.data.frame(rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=0.4))
colnames(x1)[1] <- "V1"
x2<-as.data.frame(rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=0.5))
colnames(x2)[1] <- "V1"
x3<-as.data.frame(rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=0.6))
colnames(x3)[1] <- "V1"
x4<-as.data.frame(rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=0.6))
colnames(x4)[1] <- "V1"
x5<-as.data.frame(rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=0.45))
colnames(x5)[1] <- "V1"
x6<-as.data.frame(rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=0.40))
colnames(x6)[1] <- "V1"

x7 <- as.data.frame(rbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6))

Month <- as.data.frame(c(rep(1, 200),
          rep(2, 200),
          rep(3, 200),
          rep(4, 200),
          rep(5, 200),
          rep(6, 200)))

colnames(Month)[1] <- "Month"
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x7,Month))

#Plot
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dataplot <- data.frame(
  name=c("1","2","3","4","5","6") ,  
  value=c(0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.50,0.45)
)
ggplot(dataplot, aes(x=name, y=value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

data$Month <- ordered(data$Month, levels= c("1","2","3","4","5","6"))
m1 <- glm(V1~Month, data=data, family = "binomial")
summary(m1)
```

As you can see there is a binary variable (accident YES/NO) with different proportions over the year (this could be related with temperature or other factors). I would like to test if these differences are statistically significant and ideally perform a trend analysis (in my data the proportion first increases and then decreases over the year).

Thank you so much in advance.
With all good wishes!

Comment: Please don't delete the post that was already closed and were provided with feedbacks. Instead wait for it to be reviewed in reopen queue.

Comment: Sorry about that. Please reopen my previous post. Thank you so much